# anti pornography image uploading

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the best way to programatically detect porn images?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/713247/what-is-the-best-way-to-programatically-detect-porn-images)

Im currently working on a site were i would like to offer the users to freedom to upload images to be displayed on said site. The problem is i dont want pornographic images to be displayed. i know google and other sites are already using some sort of algorithm to do this but i am wondering is there any public solutions, libraries, or recourses that i can just use in my code?

thanks any ideas are appreciated
letseatlunch

p.s. i do a lot of my coding in PHP so if preferably im looking for a solution in PHP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

they have a program 
can put it on linux

http://www.safesquid.com/html/portal.php?page=80