# Implementing Video Chat with Flash and PHP

Tags: php, javascript, flash, apache-flex, rtmp

I want to implement Video Chat with two person, the person will be randomly selected like in chatroulette. I have no idea of RTMP server so is there any opensource system that I can use or create from scratch. I am new to flash and worked on php. Can someone help me?

Thanks

Comment: Please [read this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/713247/what-is-the-best-way-to-programatically-detect-porn-images) and programmatically block all of the male appendages. :)

Comment: Check out existing solutions http://www.google.com/search?q=Video+Chat+with+Flash+and+PHP if you can't code PHP or Flash. Your question is too broad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok cool, I figured out the answer myself!
I did using Flash Peer2Peer with Adobe Cirrus. here is a sample link developers can try

[Create a simple P2P chat application](http://cookbooks.adobe.com/post_Create_a_simple_P2P_chat_application-16563.html)

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is 'no' unless you're willing to dole out a lot of money.  There's so many solutions for this, each one has pros and cons and it depends what you're really trying to do.

Comment: need a basic structure so that it can be modified according to specs.

Comment: You could try using Cirrus (Adobe's p2p solution) and have php randomize the ids that Cirrus gives back, however, it's going to be a headache to know in which state the clients are because there is no feedback from them.  For best results, you'll probably need a streaming solution, in which case you could try out BlazeDS.