# XXX image recognition software/algorithm

Tags: c#, java, image-processing, image-recognition

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the best way to programatically detect porn images?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/713247/what-is-the-best-way-to-programatically-detect-porn-images)

Here http://www.face-rec.org/algorithms/ is a good site about the face recognition. I'm looking for a solution how to disallow uploading XXX rated images. (or automatically delete them after upload).

Is here some image analyzing algorithm for this area?

Ps: pls, don't LOL me, its a serious problem... :)

Comment: Possible dup of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/713247/what-is-the-best-way-to-programatically-detect-porn-images

Comment: Exactly - 2 years old duplicate question is not an real duplicate. here is more than "how to send GET to webserver", what will not change over the years (because of protocol), but this **sure** changed. If possible, please reopen - or post news (especially open source SW) in comments. Is it a real and very serious problem.