# Is it possible to block webpages using React-JavaScript webpage?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Is it possible to create a webpage using React, that can then be used to block certain webpages. For example, blocking adult sites and user specified sites?
I know this is possible using extensions.
I don't need to know *how* it's possible, I just need to know if it is possible at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to create a webpage using React, that can be used to block certain web pages?

As I understood you, you are trying to prevent a user from visiting a web page by using another web page. The answer is **no**. You can't block a webpage using another webpage. It is the job of the browser (or extensions). You can create a browser extension/plugin instead.

But If you want to remove adult content, offensive words, or some other things like that from **your** website, it is possible. You can use a library/framework for that; just try searching on google. also checkout this: [How to recognise adult content programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14396211/how-to-recognise-adult-content-programmatically)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I guess my follow up question would be: Can I make an application using React that can block webpages? If not with React, what can I build with (that uses JS or Java).

Comment: You can build a browser extension for doing that. Check [this](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/getstarted/) for how to build extension for chrome. And for other browsers, check google.

Comment: In google chrome extensions, you can use JavaScript. And HTML/CSS (even react) for the user interface.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of that. Thank you for the recommendation, but I am intentionally choosing not to use a browser extension for certain reasons. Hence my query regarding desktop applications.

Comment: Well, I do have not much experience with the technologies of interacting with browsers using desktop applications. You can find them on google. But for making desktop applications with HTML, CSS, and javascript(even React.js), you can use [Electron.js](https://www.electronjs.org/) framework.