# computervision: nudity detection solutions comparision (opencv based or custom code) & hash-lists & client side

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, benchmarking, vision, computer-forensics

**server side:**

- List item:
- ...: x% matches found, y% false positives *(opencv +10 lines of code)*
- ...: x% matches found, y% false positives *(large custom code since 1995)*
- another:
- Minimal OpenCV C++ code:

  ```
  ....
  ....
  ```

**hash lists:**

- ..: *(financed by public money, restricted access as of ...)*
- ...: *(open access)*
- ...: , y million entries, y % new last years *(commercial $y / month)*
- ...: , x million entries, x % new last years *(commercial $x / month)*

**(serverside &) crowdsourced / crowd-verified:**

- Google images' filter: ... *(restricted access, yet not even in webmastertools for owned websites)*

**client-side:**

- another: ... *(will scan x megapixels per 50ms on a i5 2540 mobile)*
- nude.js (patrick-wied): ...

---

I completely rewrote this question, which was always closed and apparently appeared to be to wide rather than specific and "promote a link" rather than alternatives?

Task here *now* is to:
"Take inventory of all the worlds existing approaches for this development specific but widely unknown task."
(= to fill the gaps in the table above and maybe sample code/implementations)

While some windows software is marketed to parents whose kids surf the net, 
this assumable wont anytime soon appear in a wikipedia article 
*"Comparision Of Nudity detection software"* and from a development perspective. (nor on alternative.to/...  )

also this is specific, yet widely underserved nor practiced. 
Thus no single answer/link would be anything much of self-promotion/spam,  this question on the contrary is prone to such less than the average question. Yet there dont need to be any links at all and there wont be answers with personal opinions and if there could be it would help more than nothing.

Comment: With regards to #1, that's probably too open-ended for StackOverflow. #2 is a fine question; you just need to tell us what you tried, and what didn't work (be as specific as possible).

Comment: Nudity detection? Surely you're kidding…

Comment: Show me your images. I'll soon tell you if they have nudity.

Comment: Last answers on question 1. on StackOverflow seem as well already few years old. And there are only a handful of alternatives, so i dont see this beeing too general? is it an unwritten law that a good answer can only have 2 or 3 links? I imagine even if 10 people would add all alternatives that they know it would not result in more than 5 alternatives anyways.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To run nude.js, check out the [examples on this site.](http://davidwalsh.name/nudejs)

Essentially, you need to include the JS files, and then run the checking algorithm on the images you want to run it on. There are [3 functions](http://www.patrick-wied.at/blog/nude-js-update-1/): `nude.init()` `nude.load(param)` and `nude.scan(function optional)`.

**From the linked example site:**

```
nude.load(node);
// Scan it
nude.scan(function(result){ 
    alert(result ? "Nudity found in " + node.id + "!" : "Not nude");
});
```

It's also worth noting that [an article from the developer](http://www.patrick-wied.at/blog/nude-js-update-1/) recommends not using it in production mode.

> I wouldn’t recommend using the library in production mode right now
>   because the detection rate is about 60%

You may want to check out the links on [this question and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6163021/761793) on SO for alternatives.

Comment: thanks. i thought so, just beeing puzzled that after downloading the source not even the test(demo) works, despite its the same as on his site, tried 3 computers and 5 browsers...

Comment: @jonas See my update with the quote from the developer. Since he said that 2 years ago, and I can't find any updated code since then, I'd recommend scraping the whole idea of using this - save yourself some time!

Comment: @jonas If I've answered your question sufficiently, please mark it as answered. Otherwise, how else can I help? What more are you looking for?

Comment: hey=) i am not going to scrape the whole idea but make this work or something better (if anything is available).

- did you try why the included example doesnt run? 
thanks

Comment: @jonas The "examples on this site" link contains examples that run. If the example you were trying doesn't work, I'd try using the examples from the site I provided. If you have any other specific questions, I suggest you post them as a new question, you'll get better/quicker answers.