# How to programmatically identify sexually explicit images?

Tags: image, algorithm, filtering, identity, photos

Google does this successfully. Do they use an algorithm or are the images marked manually by people once and the results are used by the exact same images thus significantly reducing the number of images to go through?

Because I am not sure how else you can identify these pictures. You can use skin color but is it 100% accurate? What if the person just wore a skin colored outfit? Or are these eliminated too?

Or what if the person is fully clothed but performing sexual acts?

Comment: This question was accepted though (found after posting): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/713247/what-is-the-best-way-to-programatically-detect-porn-images

Comment: any final solution with full source code sample in .NET ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is just another image classification or object recognition problem. Searching on Scholar.Google for [Pornographic image](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&q=pornographic%20image&btnG=&as_sdt=1,43&as_sdtp=) is a great start. Neural networks would be my first attempt (and seems to be a popular choice from the pubs on Scholar).

This paper, [Recognition of Pornographic Web Pages
by Classifying Texts and Images](http://nlpr-web.ia.ac.cn/2007papers/gjkw/gk7.pdf), has a good related works section that you could investigate. It lists model-based, region-based, and feature-based as the main techniques to analyze images for pornographic content.

Your idea of using the skin color is very naive and wouldn't be very accurate (would be interesting to use as a comparison for a more sophisticated method though!).

**If I was to try to tackle the problem**, I would start with [Viola-Jones objects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viola%E2%80%93Jones_object_detection_framework) (based on [Haar cascades](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haar-like_features)), which is already implemented for you in [OpenCV](http://opencv.org/). Also read up on [neural networks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artificial_neural_network). I have used these techniques to **successfully** find particular muscles in images of people so there is no reason why you can't look for explicit content with them. (Disclaimer: This is not my field of research, only a hobby, so make sure you go into those papers!)

Comment: Thanks alot, btw what was your reason for finding muscles? Do you mean like isolating triceps in images, etc?

Comment: @JoanVenge I was extracting very particular body parts from images for a research project.

Comment: Thanks man, sounds interesting.

Comment: @Kiquenet I can't do your work for you. If I had solved this, I would be selling it or publishing it.

Comment: Not free for community Google components

Comment: @AustinHenley any demo-trial about your component ?