# What methods and algorithms now using for Naughty Detection?

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision

Interestingly, what technologies and algorithms the large companies use. I found only that the Microsoft uses the PhotoDNA technologie, but it is responsible only how photos are compared. **It is interesting also as they automatically detecting pornographic images.**

For example, are used any of methods : Skin Detection, ROI Detection, Bag-of-Visual-Words.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the best way to programatically detect porn images?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/713247/what-is-the-best-way-to-programatically-detect-porn-images)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seminal work in this field was done in [Fleck, Margaret M., David A. Forsyth, and Chris Bregler. "Finding naked people." Computer Vision—ECCV'96. Springer Berlin Heidelberg, 1996. 593-602.](https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse455/10au/notes/forsyth.pdf). The approach detects skin-colored regions and then determines whether or not the regions match predefined human shapes. More on their skin detection algorithm here: http://www.cs.hmc.edu/~fleck/naked-skin.html .

More recent papers with summaries of current methods are available:

1. http://iseclab.org/people/cplatzer/papers/sfcs05-platzer.pdf
2. http://arxiv.org/abs/1402.5792

You may also take a look at: [What is the best way to programatically detect porn images?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/713247/what-is-the-best-way-to-programatically-detect-porn-images)

**update 2016:** use a convnet. They are far better at building high resolution filters. I wrote about it in more detail here

- http://blog.clarifai.com/what-convolutional-neural-networks-see-at-when-they-see-nudity/
- https://www.slideshare.net/mobile/RyanCompton1/what-convnets-look-at-when-they-look-at-nudity

Comment: Thanks for the answer, some articles have helped me!

Comment: Sure. Btw it's customary to upvote/accept an answer if you are satisfied with it, cf https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers and https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: I gladly would have done it, but my rating is insufficient. sorry

Comment: Ah, right. Well, fun question still. Good luck with your project.